# Ошибка при добавлении элемента в динамический массив абстрактного класса c++ arduino

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, arduino

Есть массив абстрактного класса:

```
GameBase **games = new GameBase*[5];
```

Сам абстрактный класс (если надо):

```
class GameBase
{
private:
 bool End;
public:
 virtual void Init(TFT_eSPI *_tft) = 0;
 virtual void Update() = 0;
 virtual void ButtonPressed() = 0;
 virtual void Exit() = 0;

 virtual ~GameBase();

 void Run(TFT_eSPI *_tft);
};
```

Если добавлять новый элемент в массив, то возникает ошибка при компиляции:

```
Snake snake;
games[0] = &snake;
```

Ошибка:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\nodemcuv2\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

Класс змейки:

```
class Snake : public GameBase
{
private:
  TFT_eSPI *tft;
public:

  void Init(TFT_eSPI *_tft) override;
  void Update() override;
  void ButtonPressed() override;
  void Exit() override;
};
```

(уверен, что ошибка именно из-за этого, т.к. если не добавлять элемент, то все компилируется)

Что не так? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А определение GameBase и Snake у вас есть или только то, что есть? Исправит ситуацию `virtual ~GameBase() = default;`?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников спасибо! По невнимательности пропустил.